# Jump from log message to line in Eclipse when running application with Gradle

Tags: eclipse, logging, gradle, gradle-eclipse

Eclipse creates links to source files if you format your log messages like this:

```
// Clicking this in Eclipse's console window
// will take you to line 29 of MyClass.java
System.out.println("(MyClass.java:29)");
```

This works fine when compiling and running the code through Eclipse using the standard "Java Application" run configuration.

Yet when running the same program via Gradle's [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) while the same text is printed in Eclipse's console window there's no link anymore, just plain text.

Is there a way to get those links in Eclipse when running the application using Gradle?

Thanks very much in advance.

---

I'm using

- Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)
- Gradle IDE 3.6.2.201410090835-RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

As a quick-and-dirty solution you can use the Stacktrace Console functionality from Eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-stacktrace_console.htm